# Display a distinct number of rows from MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if you could please help me? I am building a food website and when you type your area code the list of all takeaways that are delivering at this area should be displayed. So far so good, but there should be displayed the type of food like this:

```
American(3)
Chinese(5)
French(10)
```

And so on. Now my question is how to take out the values from the DB and count them with PHP?

I have those column names in the DB:

id, name, address, post_code, city, food, delivery_time, delivery_cost, logo

Please tell me what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `food` defines the type of food (chinese, american), then use SQL query like this:

```
SELECT food, COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE post_code = :code GROUP BY food
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Sorry for the late replay!